# Meaning of アップ in this sentence

Tags: meaning

I need a little help with the meaning of "アップ" in this sentence.

I'm translating an interview about a stage play based on a manga.
The director wanted to add a scene where there is a wolf girl, but the mangaka was surprised and explained why she thought it was a difficult thing to do on stage:

> でも、狼少女は、漫画でならアップができるからいいけど、舞台にすると難しいということで。

I read that one of the meaning of アップ is "close-up", but I don't think this is the case.

Since a アップ is also "a boost; an increase" I was thinking of "an exaggeration" in this case, but maybe it's a stretch from my part:

> "However, a wolf girl is fine in a manga, because exaggerations can be
> done, but it's a difficult thing to do on stage."

Thank you in advance for your help!

--
Edit:

Here is the original context.

It's an interview with the main actress (Kanjiya-san) and the mangaka (Miuchi-sensei).

Here they start to talk about how good the director (G2-san) is at adapting the manga scenes for this stage play.

The manga focuses on theater so all the names between quotation marks are names of plays inside this stage version.
One of these plays should feature a wolf girl.

> 貫地谷:
> 今稽古ですごく面白いのが、大河ドラマの沙都子の演技に対して、「この子画面で光ってるよ」と言われるシーンで、どうやるんだろうな？と思ったら、G2さんが私が主役であるかのように見える配置を考えて下さって。やっぱりそれは舞台ならではの見せ方で、すごく面白いです。
>
> 美内: なるほど。そうですね。G2さんと打ち合わせをした時に、
> 『忘れられた荒野』の芝居は外してほしくないって言ったんですよ。**でも、狼少女は、漫画でならアップができるからいいけど、舞台にすると難しいということで**。確かにそうですねと思いました。ただ、
> 『忘れられた荒野』は、紫のバラのひとの正体がばれる大事なエピソードがあるので食い下がったんですが、出来上がってきた台本を見ると、主要な要素は全部
> 『ふたりの王女』の中に入ってました。さすかだなと思いました。でもね、ちょっと残念なんですよね。貫地谷さんの狼少女が見られないっていうのがね。

Comment: Are you really sure this does not mean "close-up" (in the sense of "zooming")? For now, I think that's the most natural interpretation because that's one of the things only possible in manga. (アップする occasionally means "to warm up (before a sport game, stage performance, etc)", but that's not something you do when drawing a manga...)

Comment: Thank you everyone for your replies!
Actually, it could mean "close-up", but I'm not 100% convinced because I don't think that the lack of close-ups would be the main problem when trying to play a wolf girl, on a stage. She has to howl, look feral and such, I don't think that zooming would help a lot.
But, at this point, maybe it's just me disagreeing with the author. I'm not sure...

Comment: Is it possible to share the original context (the longer the better)? l'électeur's answer may be correct, but that usage is far from common, and it seems to be a "last resort" interpretation to me ("to complete/perfect" is something you must do with a 舞台, too...). We need to exclude other possibilities with confidence.

Comment: I edited my post. I hope it's not too confusing.

Comment: @Lono94 Okay, ガラスの仮面, right? The context is about 配置 (blocking), so now I'm almost certain this アップ is about zooming (I guess there are two characters who are standing apart from each other in the 光ってるよ scene)

Comment: Yes, ガラスの仮面!
Actually they are talking about two different scenes. Kanjiya-san is referring to a scene where the protagonist, who was playing for TV at that time, in the role of Satoko, stands out so much that she seems to shine on the tv screen.
Instead the play with the wolf girl is played on stage, without a screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This アップ does mean "close up", "zooming", i.e., enlarging a character. This is how a mangaka normally uses the word アップ, after all.

The context is about 舞台ならではの見せ方, unique ways of showing the relationship of actors on stage. In stage play, the distance of two characters does not have to follow the "real scale". Imagine a scene where there are two characters who are 100 meters apart from each other. In stage play, it's possible to physically place (配置) two actors side by side and make the audience "believe" they are apart, with the aid of facial expressions, tone of voice, stage settings, etc. On the other hand, a mangaka would place the two characters physically correctly, and can "zoom in" (アップ) them whenever necessary.

Here, Kanjiya and Miuchi are talking about two similar tricky scenes that were difficult to reproduce at real scale. The first scene was "Satoko is remotely being watched by people over TV", and Kanjiya was impressed by the G2's "trick" to efficiently keep focusing her acting, while making the audience believe there was a distance at the same time. The other scene was "a wolf girl in the wilderness", which was omitted because it was considered too difficult to reproduce as a stage play.

> でも、狼少女は、漫画でならアップができるからいいけど、舞台にすると難しいということで。
>   However, while the wolf girl (scene) is fine (=possible to efficiently depict) as a manga because I can zoom in (the characters), I was told it was difficult as a stage play (and the scene was removed in the end).